# Objective-C, Objective-C++, C++ and Scene Kit

Tags: c++, ios, scenekit, objective-c++

I've got a project that is a mix of pure C++ and Objective-C++ in order to incorporate some C++ libraries.

I've tried adding some basic `SCNScenes` into the mix. (By basic I mean a scene with a box node in it and that's it). Every time i get the error:

> Assertion failed: (renderSize.x != 0), function -[SCNRenderContextMetal _setupDescriptor:forPass:isFinalTechnique:], file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/SceneKit/SceneKit-332.6/sources/Core3DRuntime/NewRenderer/SCNRenderContextMetal.mm, line 688.

Does anyone know what causes this, and if so how can I get round it?

EDIT:

In my `ViewController.mm` I've got:

```
self.sceneView = [[SCNView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.sceneView.scene = [SCNScene scene];

SCNNode *cube = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNBox boxWithWidth:1.0 height:1.0 depth:1.0 chamferRadius:0]];
cube.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor redColor];
[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:cube];

[self.view addSubview:self.sceneView];
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: Is your frame populated?   eg 'CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];'

Comment: It is but it was being set to cgrectzero. I've changed it and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that `SceneKit` throws a fit if you set the `SCNView` frame to `CGRectZero`. There has to be at least 1 pixel of rendering real estate. Simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are starting up your SceneKit scene using a storyboard.

If so, the recent version of the SDK now requires that you set the constraints on views or else they end up having trivial size.  It might just be a function of setting constraints on your SceneKit scene.

You also need to set the frame to something valid if it isn't.   eg

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

Comment: No it's all done in code. I'll post the relevant code.

Comment: You are setting the sizes manually then?   The basic gist is that the default sizes are rubbish now.

Comment: Ah ok. I worked out that I was setting the scene view frame to cgrectzero and that was causing the problem. Stupid really.

Comment: Please add this as an answer, and accept it, to close the question.